# How to update Pandas dataframe based on the other row?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that measure the student performance `student` as below:

```
ID  TestDate    PerformanceStatus (PS)
1   15/03/2016  0
1   01/04/2016  2
1   05/05/2016  1
1   07/06/2016  1
2   15/03/2016  0
2   01/04/2016  2
2   05/05/2016  1
2   07/06/2016  3
2   23/08/2016  1
```

I want to update my table to have a new column PreviousPerformanceStatus. 
This PreviousPerformanceStatus is calculated based on the performanceStatus monitored, as below:
Note: If there is not performanceStatus recorded before the TestDate, I want to make the `PreviousPerformanceStatus = PerformanceStatus`

```
ID  TestDate    PS  PreviousPerformanceStatus
1   15/03/2016  0   0
1   01/04/2016  2   0
1   05/05/2016  1   2
1   07/06/2016  1   1
2   15/03/2016  0   0
2   01/04/2016  2   0
2   05/05/2016  1   2
2   07/06/2016  3   1
2   23/08/2016  1   3
```

I can do it with an SQL-statement, but how do I update my Dataframe with pandas.
Thanks.

Example:
(for with ID=1) The previousPerformanceStatus is calculated based on the PerformanceStatus from the "earlier" test date., so when TestDate=01/04/2016, I want to use the data from TestDate=15/03/2016. However, if I can't find any previous data, I will default the PreviousPerformanceStatus with the value in the PerformanceStatus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a `groupby` on `'ID'` and use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.bfill.html):

```
# Ensure that the dates are pd.Timestamp, and sorted.
df['TestDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TestDate'], dayfirst=True)
df = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'TestDate'])

# Perform a shift and bfill at the 'ID' group level.
df['PrevPS'] = df.groupby('ID')['PS'].apply(lambda grp: grp.shift().bfill()).astype(int)
```

You can skip the date conversion and sort if you know beforehand that your DataFrame will be sorted correctly.

The resulting output:

```
   ID   TestDate  PS  PrevPS
0   1 2016-03-15   0       0
1   1 2016-04-01   2       0
2   1 2016-05-05   1       2
3   1 2016-06-07   1       1
4   2 2016-03-15   0       0
5   2 2016-04-01   2       0
6   2 2016-05-05   1       2
7   2 2016-06-07   3       1
8   2 2016-08-23   1       3
```

Comment: why do you use `bfill`?

Comment: And next lines will do the same, for example
```df['PrevPS'] = df['PS'].shift();
df['PrevPS'] = df['PrevPS'].fillna(0).astype(int)```

Comment: @discort: To account for the requirement "If there is not performanceStatus recorded before the TestDate, I want to make the PreviousPerformanceStatus = PerformanceStatus".  Using `shift` by itself will introduce `NaN` in the first position.  You can't just fill with zero because I don't think it's guaranteed that the first status is zero; it just happens to be that way in the sample data.

Comment: @discort: If I read the question correctly, you need to perform a `groupby` because the shift is to be done at the `'ID'` level, not globally on the DataFrame.  For example, with the code you posted the first entry of the 'Previous' column for ID 2 would 1, not 0 as is displayed in the example output.

Comment: can you explain this line? `df['PrevPS'] = df.groupby('ID')['PS'].apply(lambda grp: grp.shift().bfill()).astype(int)`

Comment: `df.groupby('ID')['PS']` essentially means that the `apply` operation be performed be separately on each `'ID'` section of the dataframe (i.e., `df[df['ID']==1]`, `df[df['ID']==2]`, etc.) on the `'PS'` column.  For the `apply` operation, I'm shifting down the `'PS'` column by one place with `shift`, and making the first value the original first value by back-filling with `bfill` (otherwise it would be `NaN` since there was nothing to shift down in its place).  The `astype` is just to make sure the resulting column is integer values instead of float.